# How to solve the limit of the following trigonometric functions？

Tags: limits, functions, complex-numbers, triangles, infinity

How can i calculate limits of $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\varepsilon  \to 0} \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \cos \left[ {\left( {a + i\varepsilon } \right)x} \right] = a$, $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\varepsilon  \to 0} \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  - \infty } \left[ {\cos \left( {a + i\varepsilon } \right)x} \right] = 1$, $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\varepsilon  \to 0} \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \sin \left[ {\left( {a + i\varepsilon } \right)x} \right] = ia$ and $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\varepsilon  \to 0} \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  - \infty } \left[ {\sin \left( {a + i\varepsilon } \right)x} \right] = i$, when $a>0$ is a constant, $x$ approaches ${ \pm \infty }$ and $\varepsilon$ approaches $0$?
As far as I know, $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  \pm \infty } \sin ax$ and $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  \pm \infty } \cos ax$  have no limit at infinity. Can someone explain the above to me?
Thanks for assistance.

Comment: The result is false. Just take $a=0$, $\epsilon_n=1/n$ and $x_n=n$ for the first limit. I'm pretty sure $cos(i)\neq 0$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't make it clear that 
 is a constant and greater than $0$

Comment: IS $x$ inside or outside the cosine?

Comment: $ x$ is inside the trigonometric functions sine and cosine. Thank you.